# Class Return type when creating a method

Tags: java, oop

[UML Diagram][1]

[image: valid XHTML]

I'm studying for the midterm exam next week and I'm practicing some given examples from my professor; however, I am having some trouble with class return type methods.

I attached UML diagram just in case.

What i'm trying to understand is getPerson method in Job class. I don't think i need a array list in Job class to store all the employee. Because I have an array list already in Company class. Also return type is Employee class that I'm not sure how to get person's info using this class return type.

My problems

1. public Employee getPerson() {} in Job class
2. public boolean isVacant() {} in Job class
3. Also would you mind checking getVacantJobs, getFilledJobs, and getAllJobs methods if those are correctly built?

I used iterator to display all the stored jobs.

---------------------------Employee Class -----------------------------

```
public class Employee {
    private String name;
    private int id;

    public Employee(int id, String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id =id;

    }

    public final String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public final void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public final int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public final void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [name=" + name + ", id=" + id + "]";
    }

}
```

----------------------------Job Class--------------------------------------

```
public class Job {

    private String description;

    private int id;
    private double maxSalary;

    public Job(int id, double maxSalary, String description) {
        this.description = description;
        this.id = id;
        this.maxSalary = maxSalary;
    }

    public Job(int id, double maxSalary, String description, Employee e1) {
        this.description = description;
        this.id = id;
        this.maxSalary = maxSalary;



    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return "Job [description=" + description + ", id=" + id
                + ", maxSalary=" + maxSalary + "]";
    }

    public final String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public final void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public final double getMaxSalary() {
        return maxSalary;
    }

    public final void setMaxSalary(double maxSalary) {
        this.maxSalary = maxSalary;
    }

    public final int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Employee getPerson() {
        retrun 
    }

    public final void setPerson(Employee person) {
        this.id = person.getId();

    }
}
```

--------------------------Company Class ---------------------------

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Company {

    static ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    Iterator itr = list.iterator();


    private String name;

    public Company(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Company() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void addJob(Job j1) {
        list.add(j1);
    }

    public void removeJob(int id) {
        list.remove(id);

    }


    public ArrayList<Job> getVacantJobs() {
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            if ((itr == null)) {
                System.out.println(itr);
            }
        }
        return null;

    }

    public ArrayList<Job> getFilledJobs() {
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            if (!(itr == null)) {
                System.out.println(itr);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public ArrayList<Job> getAllJobs() {
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(itr.next());
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: When you say _"My problems: 1.  `public Employee getPerson() {}` in Job class"_ you are not explaining what your problem is, merely where it occurs.  Your question is off-topic as you haven't really explained any problem.

Comment: One problem I see is that you are confusing the `id`-attribute in `Employee` and `Job`. The UML diagram states that `Employee.id` is a string and not an int. Therefore your method `Job.setPerson()` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: thanks for your advice, i'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Add field `person` to `Job` class.

```
public class Job {

    // .....

    private Employee person;

    public Employee getPerson() {
        return person;
    }

    public final void setPerson(Employee person) {
        this.person = person;
    }

    public boolean isVacant() {
        return person == null;
    }
}
```

And add `jobs` field to `Company` class.

```
public class Company {

    // static ArrayList list = new ArrayList();  // You don't need this
    // Iterator itr = list.iterator();  // You don't need this.

    // .....

    private ArrayList<Job> jobs = new ArrayList<>();

    public ArrayList<Job> getVacantJobs() {
        ArrayList<Job> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Job job : jobs)
            if (job.isVacant())
                result.add(job);
        return result;
    }

    public ArrayList<Job> getFilledJobs() {
        ArrayList<Job> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Job job : jobs)
            if (!job.isVacant())
                result.add(job);
        return result;
    }

    public ArrayList<Job> getAllJobs() {
        ArrayList<Job> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Job job : jobs)
            result.add(job);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time typing this all out. as you seem like understanding this uml diagram. My last question is in Job class, you have isvacant method that retrurns null. Is this method for checking if there's at least one employee stored in the arraylist? or if it's empty in job array?

Comment: `isVacant()` returns the job is assigned to a person or not.  It never returns null.